# WordPress.В стилях имеется ссылка на фон,как подключить

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не подключаются фоновое изображение.Вопрос,нужно задать правильный путь ,или как подключать?

Comment: Ну вам же PhpStrom подчеркивает красным, то файл не найден.

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса непонятно, где находится ваш файл css, который вы правите. Но очевидно, что относительный путь к картинке указан неправильно - IDE подчеркивает красным путь, начиная в папки images. Если вы правите файл style.css в корне темы, то путь должен выглядеть так:

```
background: url(images/move-top.png);
```

В общем, добейтесь того, чтобы IDE не подчеркивала путь к картинке красным.